# Calling jQuery search on tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery search script that uses tabs for the user to define which search type they want to use. However, when the user searches for something and then selects a new search type (clicks on a tab) they have to go to the text box and press enter to submit their query again.

**I want to call a the search when the user clicks on the tab of their choice, without them having to resubmit the query.** How can I do this? I hope you can understand what I'm trying to describe.

My current jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^=t_]").click(function(){
        t=this.id.replace("t_","");
        $("[id^=t_]").removeClass("s");
        $("#t_"+t).addClass("s");
        return false
    });
    $("#t_search").click();
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($("#s").val().length>0){
            q=$("#s").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:""+t+".php?q="+q,
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(c){
                    $("#r").html(c);
                    $("#r").show()
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My current HTML code is:

```
<div id="n">
<a href="/" id="t_search" class="s">All</a>
<a href="/images" id="t_images">Images</a>
<a href="/videos" id="t_videos">Videos</a>
<a href="/news" id="t_news">News</a>
</div>

<form action="search" method="get">
<input type="text" id="s" name="q" maxlength="2048" autocomplete="off">
</form>

<div id="r"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

submit the form when the tab is changed:

```
$("[id^=t_]").click(function(){
    t=this.id.replace("t_","");
    $("[id^=t_]").removeClass("s");
    $("#t_"+t).addClass("s");
    if ($("#s").val()!="") {  // only when there's a search term
        $("form").submit();
    }
    return false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

You've already done half of the task.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^=t_]").click(function(){
        t=this.id.replace("t_","");
        $("[id^=t_]").removeClass("s");
        $("#t_"+t).addClass("s");
        q=$("#s").val();
        if($("#s").val().length>0){
            q=$("#s").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:""+t+".php?q="+q,
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(c){
                    $("#r").html(c);
                    $("#r").show()
                }
            });
        }
        return false
    });
});
```